# The source directory "F:/Documents/.../BulletCollision-rev2613" Does not exist, in CUSTOMBUILD file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, github, bulletphysics

So on my desktop computer I went and included the BulletPhysics library into my project, built it and so on and everything worked and everything was fine until I decided that it was kinda slow for what I was doing and thus the wrong way of doing things without something to speed things up so I switched implementations without actually removing the project in case I wanted to revisit it.

Then I went and downloaded my project onto the other computer using GitHub and tried to compile it.

Initially I had to fix the project properties to use the Solution path variables as opposed to the previous absolute path it defaulted to but I despite checking every file I knew to check, the problem still unfortunately persists.

It occurs when I try to build any or all of my sub/dependent projects.

I tried doing a search for "F:/Documents/..." in the root directory of the project, deleted or edited every file that turned up to no avail. I tried search for CUSTOMBUILD and found nothing but two log files.

To reiterate, I did go to the project properties of every project and fixed the INCLUDE directories for them, the problem persists in relation to this CUSTOMBUILD file.

My theory it has something to do with having to have originally built the dependency libraries using CMAKE (or PREMAKE, I forget which one I had to use) but checking the lists and the config files didn't show me anything illuminating.

The easy solution might be to simply remove the offending library but my little experience with git and the instability of the windows client makes that a last resort at this time (it will crash processing too many files).

I don't really know what to check next.

Just to be clear, the '...' is meant to mean 'blah blah blah my path here' for brevity.

Comment: the "f:/" tells me it's a bad config; it points to the "f" disk (which the dev probably used as his second disk holding his documents)

Comment: Right, maybe I should have been more precise, I had originally set up and compiled the project one my desktop (which has the F drive as my default github root) and then pushed/committed it to github, went to my laptop (c drive) and then pulled it and tried to compile it. I as a matter of habit because of this sort of thing always use $(SolutionDir) for my project paths and make them relative, but it isn't working for this one file that seems to only exist when compiling.

Comment: grep for that path in the make files or libs, that might point you to the culprit

Comment: I'm sorry, I use Microsoft Visual Studios, does grepping work with that?

Comment: Shows how long since I last worked with Linux, no, I'm on a Windows machine and I've already done a search as I've said in my original post. So grep wouldn't show me anything new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a similar question to mine which was answered and solved my problem. The directories were indeed a CMAKE issue; there was a custombuild item group in the project.vcxproj files for the CMAKE'd dependencies and the solution linked below solved it:

[a relative path on cmake errors if path is changed afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882071/relative-path-on-cmake-errors-if-path-is-changed-afterwards)

Basically I had to go into each .vcxproj file and eliminate the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <CustomBuild Include="..\..\Source\CMakeLists.txt">
      <Message Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">Building Custom Rule C:/cmake/Source/CMakeLists.txt</Message>
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">setlocal
"C:\Program Files\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -HC:/cmake -BC:/cmake/build --check-stamp-file C:\cmake\build\Source\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal &amp; call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% &amp; goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd</Command>
      <AdditionalInputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">C:/cmake/Source/CMakeLists.txt;C:\cmake\Source\CMakeLists.txt;C:\Program Files\CMake 2.8\share\cmake-2.8\Modules\CheckIncludeFile.cmake;C:\Program Files\CMake 2.8\share\cmake-2.8\Modules\CheckIncludeFile.c.in;C:\cmake\Source\cmConfigure.cmake.h.in;C:\cmake\Source\cmVersionConfig.h.in;C:\cmake\Source\CPack\cmCPackConfigure.h.in;C:\cmake\Source\CMakeLists.txt;%(AdditionalInputs)</AdditionalInputs>
      <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">C:\cmake\build\Source\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp</Outputs>
      <LinkObjects Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">false</LinkObjects>
      <Message Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">Building Custom Rule C:/cmake/Source/CMakeLists.txt</Message>
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">setlocal
"C:\Program Files\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -HC:/cmake -BC:/cmake/build --check-stamp-file C:\cmake\build\Source\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal &amp; call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% &amp; goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd</Command>
      <AdditionalInputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">C:/cmake/Source/CMakeLists.txt;C:\cmake\Source\CMakeLists.txt;C:\Program Files\CMake 2.8\share\cmake-2.8\Modules\CheckIncludeFile.cmake;C:\Program Files\CMake 2.8\share\cmake-2.8\Modules\CheckIncludeFile.c.in;C:\cmake\Source\cmConfigure.cmake.h.in;C:\cmake\Source\cmVersionConfig.h.in;C:\cmake\Source\CPack\cmCPackConfigure.h.in;C:\cmake\Source\CMakeLists.txt;%(AdditionalInputs)</AdditionalInputs>
      <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">C:\cmake\build\Source\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp</Outputs>
      <LinkObjects Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">false</LinkObjects>
      <Message Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='MinSizeRel|Win32'">Building Custom Rule C:/cmake/Source/CMakeLists.txt</Message>
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='MinSizeRel|Win32'">setlocal
"C:\Program Files\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -HC:/cmake -BC:/cmake/build --check-stamp-file C:\cmake\build\Source\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal &amp; call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% &amp; goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd</Command>
      <AdditionalInputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='MinSizeRel|Win32'">C:/cmake/Source/CMakeLists.txt;C:\cmake\Source\CMakeLists.txt;C:\Program Files\CMake 2.8\share\cmake-2.8\Modules\CheckIncludeFile.cmake;C:\Program Files\CMake 2.8\share\cmake-2.8\Modules\CheckIncludeFile.c.in;C:\cmake\Source\cmConfigure.cmake.h.in;C:\cmake\Source\cmVersionConfig.h.in;C:\cmake\Source\CPack\cmCPackConfigure.h.in;C:\cmake\Source\CMakeLists.txt;%(AdditionalInputs)</AdditionalInputs>
      <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='MinSizeRel|Win32'">C:\cmake\build\Source\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp</Outputs>
      <LinkObjects Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='MinSizeRel|Win32'">false</LinkObjects>
      <Message Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='RelWithDebInfo|Win32'">Building Custom Rule C:/cmake/Source/CMakeLists.txt</Message>
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='RelWithDebInfo|Win32'">setlocal
"C:\Program Files\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -HC:/cmake -BC:/cmake/build --check-stamp-file C:\cmake\build\Source\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal &amp; call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% &amp; goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd</Command>
      <AdditionalInputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='RelWithDebInfo|Win32'">C:/cmake/Source/CMakeLists.txt;C:\cmake\Source\CMakeLists.txt;C:\Program Files\CMake 2.8\share\cmake-2.8\Modules\CheckIncludeFile.cmake;C:\Program Files\CMake 2.8\share\cmake-2.8\Modules\CheckIncludeFile.c.in;C:\cmake\Source\cmConfigure.cmake.h.in;C:\cmake\Source\cmVersionConfig.h.in;C:\cmake\Source\CPack\cmCPackConfigure.h.in;C:\cmake\Source\CMakeLists.txt;%(AdditionalInputs)</AdditionalInputs>
      <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='RelWithDebInfo|Win32'">C:\cmake\build\Source\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp</Outputs>
      <LinkObjects Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='RelWithDebInfo|Win32'">false</LinkObjects>
    </CustomBuild>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Woot.